# Сортировка desc

Tags: mysql

```
Есть таблица command в ней поля

id_command
name_command 
images_command
games
win
nin
los
goal_z
goal_p
soccer
forma
```

Как сделать сортировку по убыванию с полем soccer, но что бы и остальные поля перестроились, а тоу меня получается так, всё остается на месте, а сортировка работает только в поле soccer

```
if(!isset($_GET['command']))
{
$result = mysql_query("SELECT soccer FROM command ORDER BY soccer DESC");
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);

do
{
    echo "<div class=soccer1>".$myrow['soccer']."</div>"; 
}
while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result));
}
//ВЫВОД
```

Comment: Кто вам сказал что она работает только на одном поле?

Comment: А где вы используете в запросе поля кроме `soccer`?

Comment: Остальная информация кроме `soccer` берется другими запросами?

Comment: да другими запросами

Comment: Как это делается правильно ??

Comment: Перечислите через запятую другие поля этой таблицы и тогда сможете их вывести тоже. Тогда убедитесь, что порядок меняется у всех полей одновременно. `SELECT soccer, huher, naher FROM…`

Comment: так не выходит (

Comment: Не сомневаюсь! Вам в помощь: http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ , https://toster.ru/q/6564 , http://www.internet-technologies.ru/books/category_11.html

Answer (score 2):

ORDER BY указывает порядок записей целиком, а не одного столбца. В вашем примере выводится только одно поле — по которому сортируете, на этом основании никак нельзя сделать вывод о порядке значений в других полях. Добавьте другие поля и убедитесь, что всё в порядке.

На всякий случай скажу, что SELECT…ORDER BY… не изменяет порядок следования записей в базе, а влияет на вывод только данного конкретного запроса.

Считается что в базе порядое записей неопределен вовсе. "Множество" — это неупорядоченный набор. И только в момент вывода вы можете отсортировать так, как вам удобно.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?

if(!isset($_GET['command']))
{
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name_command ,images_command,games,win,nin,los,goal_z,goal_p,soccer,forma FROM command ORDER BY soccer DESC");
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);

do
{
    echo "".$myrow['images_command']."".$myrow['name_command']."".$myrow['games']."".$myrow['win']."".$myrow['nin']."".$myrow['los']."".$myrow['goal_z']."
    ".$myrow['goal_p']."".$myrow['soccer']."".$myrow['forma']."<br>

    "; 
}
while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result));
}
//ВЫВОД 

?>
```

Вот так получилось, всем спасибо

Comment: Кстати do-while здесь не в тему. Выдает курсы Попова :) В реальности нередко случается, что запрос вернул пустой набор. А do-while выполняется, как минимум, один раз. Это вызовет ошибку.

Comment: подскажи, а как тогда правильно сделать запрос? )) учусь потихоньку)

Comment: Я писал про **Цикл**, а не про запрос! Запрос это тест в query. Классический цикл это while() { } , он проверяет условие до того, как выполнится тело цикла. http://php.net/while